# Staggered text blocks

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to create a kind of staggered text boxes lay-out (see attached picture). So far I'm not succeeding, I hope you guys are able to help. Currently the second row is not floating to the complete left, but stuck at the 2nd column level.

Thx

[Staggered lay-out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08SeB.png)

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZyuY.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C02i.png)

HTML

```
<section class= contentpage>
    <p> 1st text block </p>
    <p> 2nd text block </p>
    <p> 3rdt text block </p>
    <p> ... text block </p>
    <p> ... text block </p>
    <p> ... text block </p>
    <p> ... text block </p>
    <p> ... text block </p>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.contentpage p {
display: block;
float:left;
width: 31%;
margin: 15px
}
```

Comment: So you want to arrange a flat hierarchy of paragraph elements into 3 columns? Can you update your layout mockup with numbers, so it's clearer how they're supposed to be arranged relative to how they appear in the markup?

Comment: Serlite, lay-out updated. I want them to start a new row on the left and float up until they reach the block above in the column.